# How to Load Data from java action as other page in jquery dialog

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp

I have two JSP pages, the first page has a link like this:

```
<a id="page-help" href="#" 
   onclick="'referToDamageAssessor.do?method=showInsurantInf 
    &insurantId='+<%=temp.getPolicy().getLegalInsurant().getLegalInsurantId()%>;">
    <%=temp.getPolicy().getLegalInsurant().getFirmName()%> 
</a>
```

The second page shows data from action with session with a JSP scriptlet tag. When the user clicks the link I want to show the data in jQuery dialog. I have written this code:

**First JSP Page:**

```
<a id="page-help" href="#" 
onclick="'referToDamageAssessor.do?method=showInsurantInf&insurantId='+
    <%=temp.getPolicy().getLegalInsurant().getLegalInsurantId()%>;">
    <%=temp.getPolicy().getLegalInsurant().getFirmName()%> 
</a>
```

And this is my jQuery Dialog :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#page-help').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>').load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: "fade",
                hide: "fade",
                modal: true,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

imports jquery1.9.1.js, jquery-ui.js, jquery-ui.css

The jQuery dialog opens but is empty.

Comment: Why you are assigning the url value in to onClick? it will accept a function (handler) as value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onclick()` calls in your above anchor tags will trigger certain Javascript calls and won't work with Java servlets as seen in your code and overwriting the default behaviour isn't good practise, also the single and double parameters in the onclick handler are simply wrong as the <% temp.getPolicy() %> calls are rendered on page load as part of the Java page rather than as Javascript function return values.

You could try the following which may work - remove the single quotes and plus sign:

```
<a id="page-help" href="#" onclick="referToDamageAssessor.do?method=showInsurantInf&insurantId=<%=temp.getPolicy().getLegalInsurant().getLegalInsurantId()%>;"> <%=temp.getPolicy().getLegalInsurant().getFirmName()%> </a>
```

---

Why don't you rather change the help anchors and call a function with parameters?

**Help links**

```
<a href="#" onclick="showHelp('Report damage', 'referToDamageAssessor.do?method=showInsurantInf&insurantId=<%=temp.getPolicy().getLegalInsurant().getLegalInsurantId()%>');"> <%=temp.getPolicy().getLegalInsurant().getFirmName()%> </a>

<a href="#" onclick="showHelp('Report damage', 'referToDamageAssessor.do?method=showInsurantInf&insurantId=<%=temp.getPolicy().getLegalInsurant().getLegalInsurantId()%>');"> <%=temp.getPolicy().getLegalInsurant().getFirmName()%> </a>
```

**Help caller**

```
function showHelp(title, url)
{
  var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .load(url)
    .dialog({
        show: "fade",
        hide: "fade",
        modal: true,
        title: title,
        width: 500,
        height: 300
      });    
    }
```